# Dynamic Placeholders for Usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, controls

I have an ItemsControl binded to an ObservableCollection.
Now, the items in this collection are shown in a grid of 3x5 items (3 rows, 5 items each) allowing a total of 15 items to be shown at once.
Imagine the collection not having 15, but 14 items. This will create an empty spot.
How do I fill this empty spot with a control (an image in my case)?
Keep in mind that this needs to be dynamic. If I have 10 items in the collection, I will need 5 "placeholders" to be shown.

Thanks in advance!

Current code:

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Programs}" Name="ItemsControl">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Columns="5" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="{Binding Text}" Margin="5" Background="Transparent" Foreground="White" Width="128"
                            Focusable="False" Command="{Binding ClickCommand}">
                        <Button.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform />
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Button.RenderTransform>
                        <Button.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="{Binding Image}" Height="128" />
                                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="3,10" />
                                    <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                                    <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Button.Template>
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Preview:
[image]

Comment: post your current code and XAML.

Comment: I think for this purpose more suitable `DataTemplate`.

Comment: I added code and preview, why should I use DataTemplate?

Comment: It was suggested when I did not see the code.

Comment: Can't you just do this at your collection level? have your placeholder items type part of the `ItemsSource` and just use a different DataTemplate for any item of that type? If your using MVVM, you can keep this morphed collection with live items and placeholders in your VM layer. This way if you have placeholders in the middle of your collection, it should still render your placeholder image or whatever control in that position accordingly

Comment: I could, but is this a clean way to do it? I think this will create a mess of my collection. My collection is being used for other purposes as well. Also, placeholders need to be at the very end, but you could sort the collection every time an item get's added and recreate the remaining placeholders. Though, I would have loved to see a pure WPF solution for this.

Comment: Keeping this in the VM is perfectly fine IMO, if you do not want to do that for some reason, you could use a `CompositeCollection` and have 2 separate collections. One for live items and second for placeholders. Based on size of live items, set the placeholder collection size. so pretty much `PlaceholderItems.Count = Math.Max(15 - LiveItemsSource.Count, 0)`